# How is the speed of printf affected by a presence of a forked process and '\n'?

Tags: c, shell, printf, fork

I had this simple shell like program that works both in interactive and non-interactive mode. I have simplified the code as much as I can to present my question, but it is still a bit long, so sorry for that!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>


/**
 *main-entry point for gbk
 *Return: returns the index of 0 on sucess
 */
int main(void)
{

    char *cmd = malloc(1 * sizeof(char)), *cmdargs[2];
    size_t cmdlen = 0;
    int childid, len;
    struct stat cmdinfo;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("#cisfun$ ");
        len = getline(&cmd, &cmdlen, stdin);
        if (len == -1)
        {
            free(cmd);
            exit(-1);
        }
        /*replace the ending new line with \0*/
        cmd[len - 1] = '\0';
        cmdargs[0] = cmd;
        cmdargs[1] = NULL;

        childid = fork();
        if (childid == 0)
        {
            if (stat(*cmdargs, &cmdinfo) == 0 && cmdinfo.st_mode & S_IXUSR)
                execve(cmdargs[0], cmdargs, NULL);
            else
                printf("%s: command not found\n", *cmdargs);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            wait(NULL);
    }
    free(cmd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

To summarize what this program does, it will first print the prompt `#cisfun$` , waits for an input in interactive mode and takes the piped value in non-interactive mode, creates a child process, the child process checks if the string passed is a valid executable binary, and if it is, it executes it other wise it prints a command not found message and prompts again.

I have got this program to work fine for most of the scenarios in interactive mode, but when I run it in non-interactive mode all sorts of crazy (unexpected) things  start to happen.

For example, when I run `echo "/bin/ls"|./a.out`, (*`a.out` is the name of the compiled program)*
you would first expect the `#cisfun$`  message to be printed since that is the first thing performed in the while loop, and then the output of the `/bin/ls` command, and finally `#cisfun$`  prompt, but that isn't what actually happens. Here is what happens,

[image]

1. It is very weird the `ls` command is run even before the first print message. I, at first, thought there was some `threading` going on and the `printf` was slower than the child process executing the ls command. But I am not sure if that is true as I am a noob. and also things get a bit crazier if I was printing a message with `'\n'` at the end rather than just a string. (if I change `printf("#cisfun$ ");` to `printf("#cisfun$\n");`) the following happens,

[image]

It works as it should, so it got me thinking what is the relation between `'\n'`, `fork` and speed of `printf`. Just in short what is the explanation for this.

2. The second question I have is, why doesn't my program execute the first command and go to an interactive mode, I don't understand why it terminates after printing the second `#cisfun$`  message. By checking the status code (255) after exit I have realized that the effect is the same as pressing `ctr+D` in the interactive mode, which I believe is exited by the `getline` function. But I dont understand why `EOF` is being inserted in the second prompt.

Comment: 1. output is usually _line buffered_, that's why appending a newline makes your prompt appear before the output of ls.

Comment: In practice, *always* call [fflush(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before [fork(2)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: @Peter Thank you, but I am sorry can you be a little bit more noob friendly about what line buffered means.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Thank you so much, let me read the manuals for fflush

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you again, I didn't completely understand what fflush does from the man pages, but fflush(stdout); seems to fix the first problem. I will do more reading to understand what and how fflush do its thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin/1716621#1716621 may help.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you, that shure did help. Does anyone have an idea why the 2 question could be resolved

Comment: When you pipe input into your program, its standard input is a pipe.  When it has read all the data from the pipe, end-of-file is signaled on standard input, exactly as if you pressed Ctrl-D on the terminal. If you think about it, this is what you want from a pipe; it would be weird if you tried to pipe data into `sort` and after processing the data, it started expecting you to type more data on the terminal.

Comment: If you really want to become interactive after the pipe data is finished, you'll have to manually open something like `/dev/tty` and start reading on it instead of standard input, but that's probably not a good design.  Rather, if you want your shell to run interactively, don't run it in a pipeline in the first place.

Comment: @NateEldredge, Ok that is the information I needed. Thank you so much! Just, One more question, why isn't the EOF signaled during the first getline call. or does a piped data comes in two packets, such that the first one reads the actual data, and the EOF when tried to be read for the second time.

Comment: @EHM: If there is data available to be read, `getline` will read it.  If there is no data but the writer still has the pipe open, `getline` will block until there is data.  If there is no data and the other end of the pipe has closed, `getline` indicates EOF.  I don't know what you mean by "two packets".

Comment: @EHM: But this is the same behavior you see when reading from a terminal. `getline` has no way to both return data and indicate EOF on a single return.  You have to call it again to find out that EOF has been reached.

Comment: Thanks makes sense now